# xpath to find a node with optional attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to search across multiple XML files for nodes with an optional attribute. The files missing the attribute I am looking for do not declare the namespace it belongs. I am searching using a simple XPath as in the following example:

Here I am interested in the `other_attribute` of `node`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<otherfile xmlns:xs="something" xmlns:optional="something_else">
  <node attribute = "hohoho" optional:other_attribute= "mary Xmass">
  </node>
</otherfile>
```

And I am matching it using the XPath `//@optional:other_attribute`. However, when trying to do the same in the following file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file xmlns:xs="something">
    <node attribute = "hohoho">
    </node>
</file>
```

The search fails because the namespace `optional` is not declared in the second example file. Is there a way to do a conditional search for the attribute with using the Xpath syntax?

Comment: Do you want to fetch node either with `@optional:other_attribute` or with `@other_attribute`? Or you want to fetch node with either `@optional:other_attribute` or `@attribute`? Can you clarify? It's not clear from description.

Comment: Sorry didn't explain it very well, what I would like to do is to fetch `@optional:other_attribute` *only* if it exists. My problem is that the Xpath query fails if the namespace is not declared instead of just returning nothing (node does not exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
//@*[name()="optional:other_attribute"]
```

Comment: Thanks @DonnyFlaw, however I tried `//@*[local-name()=("other_attribute")]` and it seems to work most of the time. If I understand correctly it will match any attribute named `other_attribute` regardless of namespace. So when I have attributes from other namespaces with the same name it also matches them. Is there a way to avoid doing so?

Comment: @DiamantisSellis try this one `//@*[name()="optional:other_attribute"]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the easiest way to do this is to switch the expression to `local-name()`. With the expression

```
//*[@*/local-name()="other_attribute"]
```

would select the correct node in the first example and select no nodes in the other.

Comment: It should be noted that this XPath is only valid in XPath 2.0 or higher.